# Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 2.4 mouse cursor disappear at top of the screen

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

Cursor of mouse disappear(at last pixels of screen).
For example. Now all ok.

[image]

And if I move mouse to the top of the monitor it disappear.

[image]

But at the same time I can click on buttons on top panel.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verbatim copy (Mint commented by me) of [Heath Jones (hjones014) post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-346/+bug/1440012/comments/17) on launchpad which solved the issue:

I finally remedied the problem, using the xorg-edgers ppa. This is what I did -

1. `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. goto additional drivers (driver manager on Linux Mint) and select driver 349.16 (at the moment of writing is 355)
4. reboot
5. goto software/updates (Software Sources->PPAs on Mint) and goto the "Other Software" tab and UNCHECK the xorg-edgers ppa. I DID NOT PURGE THIS PPA.

The reason why I nixed this ppa is because after selecting driver 349, the software updater would try to pull in other updates from the xorg-edgers ppa which kept crashing my system. This allowed me to keep the driver 349 and not pull in any other updates. If you do a `ppa-purge`, it will also nix the driver, hence why i just unchecked it in the sources tab.

Comment: Selecting the newest driver available in the official repository solved the issue as well. No need to add xorg-edgers ppa.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the option

```
Option "hw_cursor" "off"
```

on the `Device` section of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` solves this issue but creates other (more annoying) issues. **[Disclaimer]** messing with the xorg.conf can screw up your graphics and you'd be unable to log in. Proceed with caution, backup your xorg.conf and know how to log in to your system with a live CD/usb or drop to a shell that doesn't need the X server.

Also, switching to the nouveau driver solves it too.

None of the aforementioned solutions are acceptable for me. I'll keep digging and update the answer.